# How to view pages that require log in with Visual Studio 2012 Page Inspector?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, page-inspector

Page Inspector does not open files that require log in.

-VS 2012 Ultimate.

-MVC 4.

-browser set to IE v10

-project is set to debug

All pages that do not require log in work fine.
Pages that do require log in open on the log in page.
Logging in takes you straight to the logged-out homepage.

The result is the same when I select Page Inspector from the top-level of the solution explorer or from a specific file.

So, how can I use PageInspector on files that require being logged in?

Thanks
Stephen